# Сортировка перед GROUP_CONCAT и DISTINCT?

Tags: mysql

Не могу придумать как перед GROUP_CONCAT и DISTINCT отсортировать по `ordering`

так не сортирует так

```
SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `photo` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `photoz` 
FROM `b_photo` 
WHERE 1 
GROUP BY `divan_id` 
ORDER BY `ordering` ASC
```

Comment: подзапросом например.

Comment: Включить адекватный ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode и понять, что запрос некорректен вовсе и ваша СУБД ничего не гарантирует о том, что вы получите вместо результата.

Comment: В качестве параметра функции [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) можно указать требуемую сортировку конкатенируемых значений.

Comment: @akina Спасибо, за совет и правда GROUP_CONCAT() принимает order by я и не знал, вечно до документации руки не доходят